# How to access a file with PHP in a virtual directory on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7

Here is my problem: I have a website running on IIS 7 + PHP 5.3. There is a virtual directory in the website hierarchy called "vd" which contains flash files.

**myApplication**
- test.php
- vd
    - animation1.swf
    - animation2.swf
- ...

So, it's easy to reach the swf files with a browser, you just have to put the directory name in the url: http://www.mySite.com/vd/animation1.swf

However, I would like to use the [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function on my animations in a PHP script. But in this case, php can't find the file:

```
<?php
    // test.php
    var_dump(getimagesize('vd/animation1.swf')); // false
?>
```

It seems to make sense because anyway '/' aren't even the right directory separator for windows. But I just can't figure out how to make getimagesize works through a virtual directory, I tried a lot of stuff without success (using the [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant, using [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function ...).

Of course, I could use the real path in my script but it would be easier for me to be able to do that throught the virtual path.

Any help would be greaty appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: I would add that the problem is probably not your directory separator, but a path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not going through the web server but rather the OS to get the file. So, no web server virtual-to-real translations will take place. You will need to use the real path of the file. You could make a web request on the file and deduce the size in that manner but that is very inefficient. It makes much more sense to just do it right through the OS.

Simply create a variable/define/class constant or whatever you prefer to store the real path of the pertinent directory. Then just append `animation1.swf` to that in your code.

Comment: Could always force PHP to go through the http layer by providing a full absolute URL to the .swf file, but that's far too painful an idea to even consider seriously.

Comment: @Marc B: That's what I was referring to when I said "You could make a web request...". I agree that it's not the way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll use a class constant to store the path to the file as you suggested.